# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is my code. When I run this I get an error saying :

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=6 length=6

```
for(i=1;i<6;i++)

{
   String s = getSharedPreferences("TEXT", 0).getString("DATA" + sequenceNumber, null);


                    if(s!=null){
                            String[] numb= new String[6];
                            numb[i]=s;
                            Bundle b=new Bundle();
                            b.putStringArray(key, numb);
                            Intent i=new Intent();
                            i.putExtras(b);
                            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, NotifyEmergencyCall.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            }

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank You.

Comment: I have a CheckBox. So when it is checked a number is added to the Shared Preference. There are 5 numbers possible and it is fixed..

Comment: Arrays in Java start at 0. If you have a String[6], the indices are 0,1,2,3,4,5 - not 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: why you creating the array inside the loop, it can be outside of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `for(i=1;i<6;i++)` with `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`

Comment: The array exception is gone but i have some other exceptions, which I think is not related to this..Thank You

Comment: the exception appeared because new String[6] returns an array with elements with index from 0 to 5 inclusive and in for you started from 1 to 6, which was wrong